# Reducing buckets by key and hour with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, mapreduce

I have a bucket of KPIs (Key Performance Indicator) with values in the following structure:

```
{
    A : [{x : [(hour, value),(hour, value)], y : [(hour, value)]}],
    B : [{d : [(hour, value),(hour, value)], e : [(hour, value)]}]
}
```

where `A` and `B` are buckets, `x, y, d, e` are KPIs (keys) with a list of `(hour, value)` tuples.

For each `(bucket, key, hour)`, I want to find the sum and count such that:

`{(Bucket, Key, Hour): (sum, count)}`

What is the most concise and efficient way of doing this in python ? Most of the ways I come up for grouping by hour and reducing are really long.

Note that libs such as `numpy` and `pandas` are available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to succeed:

a) Flatten your list

b) Create pandas DataFrame

c) Do your tasks

```
t = {
    'A' : [{'x' : [(3, 1),(5, 2)], 'y': [(4, 1)]}],
    'B' : [{'d' : [(4, 3),(4, 1)], 'e' : [(3, 2)]}]
}

t_flatten = [(a,b,c,d) for a in t.keys() for b,x in t[a][0].items() for c,d in x]
print(t_flatten)
[('A', 'y', 4, 1), ('A', 'x', 3, 1), ('A', 'x', 5, 2), 
 ('B', 'e', 3, 2), ('B', 'd', 4, 3), ('B', 'd', 4, 1)]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(t_flatten)
df.groupby([0,1,2]).sum()  # Grouped by bucket, key, hour
df.groupby([0,1,2]).count()
```